# What does 给盯背过去 mean in 差点没把人家给盯背过去?

Tags: meaning

The full sentence was more or less:

> 差点没把人家给盯背过去

I was wondering if it was a phrase, or if it just meant that they were staring at the person's back.

Comment: "背过去" means to turn around. A more natural version of your sentence could be "你老是盯着他, 弄得人家都背过去不敢看你了".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this means that you are staring at people in a rude way which makes them so uncomfortable that they might want to turn their back at you to avoid eye contact.

the "背" here is not a noun but a action which is performed by the person who is being stared at. Hope this will help.